# GCP Composer didn't apply new value in Environment Variables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

GCP Composer didn't apply new value in Environment Variables

As I have a connection string and put it under a new key in Environment Variables then save it. And after a while, I'd changed the host name in the connection id and save again, but this time the Composer still used the old config even though the Composer itself already stated that "This environment is running" which also means it finished the changing Environment Variables completely.

I already refreshed and checked for what I changed, the new value was there too. But running a new task with composer and it still used the old connection id.
There is no code that contain that connection id.

So weird, or I missed something.

Comment: Have you changed the key value in Airflow configuration in the composer environment? How are you running the task?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT, I changed the value in Composer Environment already. After the Composer stated that it finished updating the environment, I open the Airflow UI and run the DAG by triggering it.

Comment: Can you disable and enable the Cloud Composer API, Set the `AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE = yes` then try to add the variable? If this doesn't work please provide the composer version, airflow version and variable you are trying to add.

Comment: it seems to be work, but turning off api makes all business stop for a bit. Thank bro :D

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by disabling and then enabling the Cloud Composer API.

Also, the `AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE` has to be set to `yes`.